# redirecting to another page after form submission

Tags: php, html, forms

I have in `header.php` (which is the header of each page) a search form.
After form submission I want to redirect users to page: `site.com/search-$VALUE-100`.

I've tried with:

```
$value = $_POST['value'];
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/', $value))
{
    header("Location: search-".$value."-100");
}
}
```

and HTML:

```
<form method="get">
<input type="text" name="value" value="search" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" />
<input type="submit" name="search" class="image" value="" />
</form>
```

Now code sent to:

```
page.php?value=a&search=
index.php?value=a&search=
user.php?value=a&search=
somepage.php?value=a&search=
```

Comment: Apart from the answers using `$_GET`, you may want to throw a `+` in your regex, to be able to search for something longer than just one letter: `if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $value))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `GET` method not `POST`, so to access this value , use `$_GET`:

```
  $value = $_GET['value'];
  if(isset($_GET['search']))
  {
    if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/', $value))
    {
      header("Location:search-".$value."-100");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = $_GET['value'];
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/', $value)){
        header("Location: /search-".$value."-100");
    }
}
```

this should do it

Answer (score 0):

First thing's first you have to declare action a.k.a. php script that will handle request from any page, and you have to declare method to be POST if you want to have values in $_POST:

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
```

Than in search.php do your stuff:

```
$value = $_POST['value'];
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
  if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/', $value))
  {
    header("Location: search-".$value."-100");
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary if page that you are on will handle the proccessing. But if you want to handle action in only one place and call it from different pages than what I suggested would be a good practice. If you do it like that than you can have that code in only one place and call it from wherever you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/search-'.$value.'-100');
```